# System.Timers.Timer() Firing multiple times due to aggregation of Elapsed Events

Tags: c#

I want to have a section of my code start a timer once it's called, and I want this timer to keep running until I quit the whole program. My problem is, each time I call OnSomethingHappens() , the Elapsed events aggregate (despite my effort with -= ) and the timer starts firing one extra time (or at least this is what I think is happening). I have also tried defining the timer within the class, to no avail. Here's the related part of my code:

```
public override void OnSomethingHappens()
    {
        Timer aTimer= new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed -= (sender, e) => DoSomethingElse(sender, e);
        aTimer.Stop();
        aTimer.Close();
        aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => DoSomethingElse(sender, e);
        aTimer.Interval = 1000;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true; // I want the timer to keep working, but only fire once each time
        Console.WriteLine("Enabling Timer aTimer");
        aTimer.Start();
}
```

I cannot use static (not sure how that would help but I saw timers being defined as static in many sources) because this class has many instances, and I want them to have separate timers.

Thank you.

Comment: Just keep the timer's AutoReset at *false*.  Call its Start() method at the end of the Elapsed event handler to ensure it keeps ticking.  You can never firehose your program that way.

Comment: If you create a new timer on each call to the method, each of those timers are going to keep raise an Elapsed event, meaning that you could have 20 timers running each raising its own elapsed event (20 in total) - is this what you want? How do you gracefully stop all the timers when the application closes?

Comment: @sondergard : Yes, that is precisely my problem. I don't want 20 Elapsed Events, I only want one that keeps running. How can I write it so that it only adds 1 Elapsed Event, and stops adding afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should really only create once instance of the timer, and hook up one event listener. With your current code, a new timer is being created, with an event listener, every time the method is called. Instead make the timer a class variable, and hook up the event listener in the constructor.

You can start the timer in the OnSomethingHappens, but what do you want to happen on subsequent calls to the method? Should the timer restart, or just continue?

You would probably also want to make the class IDisposable, or at least provide a Stop method to stop the timer when the application closes.

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass, IDisposable
{
   private Timer _timer;
   private volatile bool _isStopped = true;

   public MyClass()
   {
       _timer = new Timer();
       _timer.Interval = 1000;
       _timer.Elapsed = OnTimerElapsed;
   }

   public void Stop()
   {
       _isStopped = true;
       _timer.Stop();
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      if (_timer != null)
      {
          Stop();
          _timer = null;
      }
   }

   protected override void OnSomethingHappens()
   {
       if (_timer.Enabled)
       {
          // Restart or do nothing if timer is already running?
       }
       else
       {
          _isStopped = false;
          _timer.Start();              
       }
   }

   private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs a)
   {
      if (_isStopped)
      {
          // If the Stop method was called after the Elapsed event was raised, don't start a long running operation
          return;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: your IDisposable Implementation is not complete , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx

Comment: True, but the question was about the Timer logic, so I skipped the dispose logic.

Answer (score 9):

Start your timer without the AutoReset and restart it at the end of the DoSomethingElse.

```
aTimer.AutoReset = false;
aTimer.Start();

DoSomethingElse(..)
{
   // do stuff here
   aTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: OK, but what about  aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => DoSomethingElse(sender, e); adding multiple Elapsed Events? How do I stop each of those from firing repeatedly?

Comment: You only ever have the one timer running and that timer does not auto restart. It invokes your "do something" on elapsed and when u have done what you want you restart it. Only every one.

Comment: this should be the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

if each instance of this class uses his own timer  , so static is no needed.

```
    private Timer _aTimer;

    public void OnSomethingHappens()
    {  
        if (_aTimer != null)
        {    
            _aTimer.Enabled = true;  // start timer
            return;
        }

        _aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _aTimer.Elapsed += DoSomethingElse;
        _aTimer.Interval = 1000; // every 1 second
        _aTimer.Enabled = true;  // start timer
    }

    private void DoSomethingElse(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {    
        _aTimer.Enabled = false; // stop timer
        // do w/e you want

    }
```

Comment: But will it not keep adding new Elapsed Events with _aTimer.Elapsed += DoSomethingElse; and then keep firing them multiple times? How can I stop adding new Elapsed Events if one Event already exists?

Comment: OnSomethingHappens() will call DoSomethingElse() after 1 second , when DoSomethingElse() is called , it stops the timer. 

OnSomethingHappens() creates _aTimer only once PER INSTANCE , if it's a static , it will be create only once.


Enable=true/false is the same as start/stop . I prefer the Enable way.
Try the code , thing about what you really need, who call OnSomethingHappens and when... good luck